# Url Rewrite redirect to error page

Tags: php, url

i am doing a project using php.I have rewrite some dynamic url.

**http:// domain.com/?a=username**

i was rewrite the url into

**http:// domain.com/username**

in index page  will select value from database using  $_GET['a'] value.If  $_GET['a'] will not found on the database it will produce error message.Actually my problem is server will contain the **css** folder. when getting an css file from the **css** it will redirected into error page . please help me anyone to overcome this problem

code is

```
   $cat=$_GET['a'];
   $sql="SELECT *  FROM `content` WHERE category=$cat";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$no=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($no>0)
{

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
          $id=$row['id'];
         } 

        S($id,$cat,$sub,$year);
}
else
{echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT='0; URL=error.php'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file above the RewriteRule, add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Well, in fact the first one is the rule you need, the second just makes sure you are able to access another directory in future (for example you want to have some other script inside subdir)

Answer (score 0):

do this:

1. create a public directory for assets like js / css
2. have your .htaccess (or whatever you're using to do clean urls) point all requests to begin with the path of your public folder path
3. set your A param in the code to be like this `$path = !empty($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : '';`

by doing it this way, you get these benefits:

mysite.com/someextension => your `url = someextension`

and

you can hit your assets with a direct url: `mysite.com/public/css/style.css`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
if(preg_match('/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\.css$/', $_GET['a'], $url))
{
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    echo file_get_contents('./css/' . $url[0]);
    exit();
}
```